# React: make DOMElement UNhoverble

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

im changing my `div id=MenuBarPropertyDiv` element display property, by changing the state to "none" or "block" depending on mouse hover on other `div id=topMenuBar_hardware` element. 
now this div have a child icon (i) element looks like this

```
<div className="topBarItem" id="topMenuBar_hardware"
            onMouseEnter={eventEnter} onMouseOut={eventOut}>
            <i className="fa fa-anchor" aria-hidden="true">
            </i>
             &nbsp; hardware</div>
```

the problem is: when i hover the icon inside the div, the function `onMouseOut` of  that same div, is triggered and change my state to "none" and i need to leave the whole `<div>` to make my state change to "block" again. how do i make React ignore the `<i>` element and make it invisible to the mouse? 
or there is another way around this?

this is the display code

```
   class HomePage extends Component {
       constructor(props) {
           super(props)
           this.state = { topMainBarItem: {display:"none",name:"init"} }
           this.mouseOnMenuBarItem = this.mouseOnMenuBarItem.bind(this)
           this.mouseOutMenuBarItem = this.mouseOutMenuBarItem.bind(this)

    }

    mouseOnMenuBarItem(me) {
        this.setState({ topMainBarItem: {display:"block","name":me.target.id} })

    }
    mouseOutMenuBarItem(me) {
        this.setState({ topMainBarItem: {display:"none","name":me.target.id}  })

    }

    render() {


        return (
            <div >
                {topHeadBar(this.mouseOnMenuBarItem, this.mouseOutMenuBarItem)}
                <div id="MenuBarPropertyDiv"
                     style={{ "display": this.state.topMainBarItem.display }} >
                      this is what you see when hovering the </div>
                <div className="container">

                </div>


            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css to remove pointer-events:

```
style={{ "display": this.state.topMainBarItem.display, pointerEvents: "none" }}
```